Angular: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked
I have a material modal component in my Church application.
<h2 mat-dialog-title>{{ isEdit ? 'Edit Group' : 'New Group' }}</h2>

<form (ngSubmit)="saveGroup()">
    <mat-form-field class="w-full">
        <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="group.name" name="name" required />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="w-full">
        <mat-label>Group Type</mat-label>
        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="group.groupType.id" name="groupType" required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let type of groupTypes" [value]="type.id">
                {{ type.name }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
        <textarea matInput [(ngModel)]="group.description" name="description"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>

    <div mat-dialog-actions>
        <button mat-button type="button" (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</button>
        <button mat-button color="primary" type="submit">{{ isEdit ? 'Update' : 'Save' }}</button>
    </div>
</form>

And here is the TS
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { ChurchGroup, GroupTypes } from '../groups.models';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { GroupService } from '../groups.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-new-group-modal',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [FormsModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatSelectModule, MatButtonModule, CommonModule],
    templateUrl: './new-group-modal.component.html',
    styleUrl: './new-group-modal.component.scss',
})
export class NewGroupModalComponent implements OnInit {
    group: ChurchGroup;
    groupTypes: GroupTypes[]; // To hold group types data
    isEdit = false;
    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NewGroupModalComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: { group: ChurchGroup },
        private groupService: GroupService, // Service to fetch group types
    ) {
        this.group = data.group || { groupId: 0, name: '', groupType: { id: 0, name: '' }, description: '' };
        this.isEdit = !!data.group;
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.loadGroupTypes();
    }

    loadGroupTypes(): void {
        console.info('Load group types');
        this.groupService.getGroupTypes().subscribe((types: GroupTypes[]) => {
            console.info(JSON.stringify(types));
            this.groupTypes = types;
        });
    }

    saveGroup(): void {
        // Handle group save logic here
        this.dialogRef.close(this.group);
    }

    onCancel(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close(null);
    }
}

Here the console.info(JSON.stringify(types)); returns
[{"id":1,"name":"PrayerGroup"},{"id":2,"name":"SundaySchool"},{"id":3,"name":"YouthLeague"}]

So in flow I have below thigs in console
Load Group Types

Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'. Expression location: FuseLoadingBarComponent component. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100
    at throwErrorIfNoChangesMode (core.mjs:11842:11)
    at bindingUpdated (core.mjs:16178:17)
    at Module.ɵɵproperty (core.mjs:17467:9)
    at FuseLoadingBarComponent_Template (loading-bar.component.html:1:16)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:12159:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:13392:13)
    at detectChangesInView (core.mjs:13617:9)
    at detectChangesInViewIfAttached (core.mjs:13580:5)
    at detectChangesInComponent (core.mjs:13569:5)
    at detectChangesInChildComponents (core.mjs:13630:9)

[{"id":1,"name":"PrayerGroup"},{"id":2,"name":"SundaySchool"},{"id":3,"name":"YouthLeague"}]

I didnt understand the reason why that error.
FYI below the model for group types
export interface GroupTypes {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

So there is no error when i comment the loadgrouptype method (API call)

It seems that the problem in the code is that the Types group is updated asynchronously after Angular has already finished checking for changes, what you can do is wrap the assignment in setTimeout to postpone the update to the next cycle of checking for changes. There are a lot of questions about it here.

@AgotaKristof Sorry I didnt understand that correctly. Could you please give me lil more details

ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError occurs when a value is changed after Angular has already performed its change detection. In your case, the error occurs because the groupTypes array is populated asynchronously in the ngOnInit() method. When the data is loaded and groupTypes is updated, Angular detects the change after the view has already been checked, causing an error.

One of the ways to prevent this error is to make the change take place simply in the next cycle - you can wrap the change in setTimeOut with a value of 0, and the error should be resolved,
Here is a more detailed explanation on the subject: https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4
